# sql как добавить 0 перед каждым числом

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть select;

```sql
select group_name,
case
when LEN(operator_code)=2 then CONVERT(varchar, CONCAT('0', operator_code ))
else operator_code
end 'Code'
from operator_send_channel_type
```

Если ставлю 1, то все отрабатывает, 1 добавляется перед числами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: проще использовать функцию `LPAD`

Answer (score 3):

Как уже упоминалось @nörbörnën, лучше использовать функцию `LPAD()`.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gYvnd8pY)

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE operator_send_channel_type (operator_code VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO operator_send_channel_type (operator_code)
VALUES ('12'), ('35'), ('770');

SELECT LPAD(operator_code,3,'0') as operator_code
FROM operator_send_channel_type;
```

**Результат**

| operator_code |
| --- |
| 012 |
| 035 |
| 770 |

Answer (score 1):

```
CONVERT(varchar, CONCAT('0', operator_code ))
```

Попробуйте сначала превратить в строку, а потом делать конкатенацию:

```
CONCAT('0', CONVERT(varchar, operator_code ))
```